# Why did Mr Harrington say American proverb in this scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In [*Spider-Man: Far From Home*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home), Mr Harrington and his team enters a building:

> Mr Harrington: **The squeaky wheel gets the upgrade grease**. Everyone get
>   settled, rest up because tonight, big surprise, is Prague's annual
>   Carnival of Lights.

Proverb indicates problems something like that. Why did Mr Harrington say the American proverb in this scene?

Comment: I guess he should have used a Czech proverb as he was in Prague, idk ‍♂️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The squeaky wheel gets the grease" generally means "those that complain get benefits" (usually, but not always, the benefits are ones that they feel they are due).  A student had asked why they were at such a fancy and classy location, and Mr. Harrington was taking credit, saying, in essence, that the upgrade they got was because his complaints about earlier problems caused them to add this additional high-class experience (which he might well have believed).